# Want to reduce dependancy

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I am working on a project which has multiple modules. Like module for blogs, images, news, notice etc.
Now each module is independent but it is somewhere associated with the main Auth module which manages users.
So now I have to add user_id field to each table for the particular module, e.g posts table of blog will contain user_id field, news table will contain user_id field etc... which will relate to id field of users table.
In turn I am repeating task of adding this field to each module's main model entity.

Is there any way/package like commendable traits with which I can eliminate this task?
or is there any design pattern to follow for this?

Thanks for any help